# Redash How to create table visualization inside a table visualization

Tags: redash

Is it possible to create a table visualization in Redash and when i click on a row it will collapse (or any other solution) and display a table of related data?

For example if i created a table visualization of all customers in my database (one query) and if i click on a customer (row) then it will show me all the orders the purchased (another query)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add a weblink to the dahsboard that has your `orders the purchased` as a widget.

A simple html [a href](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp) works just fine.

```sql
SELECT '<a href="https://myredash-server/dashboard/mydash?p_myparam={{ date.start }}">View mydash</a>' as link
```